# Data frame (Pandas) filling Missing Values

Tags: python, pandas, missing-data

We are asked to fill missing values in a column of a data frame (let's say df['A']) based on the following assumptions:
1- If the value of df['B'] for the same row is greater than 1000, use 0.
2- Otherwise, use the mean of df['A']

I used the following code and it worked well.

```
mean_value = df['A'].mean()
df['A'].loc[(df['A'].isna()) & (df['B] > 1000)] = 0
df['A'].fillna(mean_value, inplace = True)
```

But you can see that two lines of code are used for filling the null values. Is there any method to replace it by just one line?

Comment: Did you mean `df.loc[(df['A'].isna()) & (df['B] > 1000), 'A'] = 2000`? Why do you want to do it in 1 line?

Comment: seems like a perfectly good approach to me?

Comment: I am interested to know whether there is an easy method or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check `np.select`

```
con1=(df['A'].isna()) & (df['B'] > 1000)
con2=df['A'].isna()
df['A']=np.select([con1,con2],[0,df['A'].mean()],default=df.A)
```

Answer (score 1):

May be you can use this

```
check1 = df['A'].isna()
check2 = (df['A'].isna()) & (df['B'] > 1000)
df['A'] = np.where(check1 , np.where(check2,2000,df['A'].mean()), df['A'])
```

Example Input

```
      A     B
0   5.0     500
1   NaN     2000
2   3.0     1500
3   4.0     1100
4   NaN     7
```

Example Output

```
      A     B
0   5.0     500
1   2000.0  2000
2   3.0     1500
3   4.0     1100
4   4.0     7
```

Comment: Need to add a test for `A.isna()` or all values will be changed. I think row 2 & 3 are wrong from OP's definition.

Comment: @AChampion Thanks for noticing it, i missed the part about replacing ONLY NaN's. Code updated.

Answer (score 1):

You may try this arithmetic way although one-liner in this case just makes it hard to read. Since you edited your question from `2000` to `0`, there is no need the addition. So, the answer is

```
df['A'] = df.A.fillna((df['B'] <= 1000) * df.A.mean())
```

Answer (score 0):

I used the following line of code and it worked but I still believe there should be a more gentle way to solve this problem.

```
df['A'] = df.apply(lambda x: x['A'] if not(np.isnan(x['A'])) else (0 if x['B'] > 1000 else mean_value), axis = 1)
```

Any idea?